# See the request body in ARC

Tags: advanced-rest-client

Is there a way to see the request body after I sended to server? I opened the developer toggle inside of ARC, but I access Network tab, I can't see my request. The only request showed is the collective, a request for google analytics.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't use Chrome's networking.
To see the message go to response details, request headers, source message.

[image: <code>enter image description here</code>]